# Creating an overflow for a 8 bit binary

Tags: computer-architecture

Hi everyone I am new to this site, apologies if this is in the wrong section.
I have made a 8 bit diagram to represent 2's compliment however when the binary reaches the maximum of 255 I would like to add a storage device such as a flip flop to act as a overflow to store the data.
Could anyone help me please?

I would appreciate it

Thank you.[8 bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jtnd0.jpg)

I used the diagram of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/226270/use-of-d-flip-flop-in-serial-adder
to follow.

Comment: Are you saying you're having trouble saving this diagram in the application, or something else. Please use the EDIT button to clarify and improve this question. Right now it is difficult to tell what you are asking, and it seems as though you're asking a very theoretical question which is not going to be a good fit here.

Comment: I have edited does this make it any clearer? Thank you for your response.